# Django get uploaded images

Tags: django

I have created a model to get images and upload them to upload folder and the link is available in database.
But when I call the image in my index.html it does not work

settings.py

```
  USERFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [
                     USERFILES_DIRS,
                     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
                    ]
```

models.py

```
class MyShoes(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
display_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload', height_field=None,width_field=None, max_length=None)
featured = models.BooleanField()
```

views.py

```
def myIndex(request):
myShoes = models.MyShoes.objects.all()
return render(request,'index.html',{'myshoes':myShoes})
```

HTML

```
{% for x in myshoes %}
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{x.display_picture}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{x.title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{x.description}}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{x.price}}</p>
      {{x.display_picture}}
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {%endfor%}
```

here in my HTML i am getting the url *'upload/shoe-1384193-1279x850.jpg'* but HTML does show it in img tag

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
# {{x.display_picture.url}}  <!-- from the media url -->
{% for x in myshoes %}
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{x.display_picture.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{x.title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{x.description}}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{x.price}}</p>
      {{x.display_picture}}
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {%endfor%}
```

More about image (media) in django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: No didn't work I feel i my path is wrong my BASE_DIR has my upload folder and if I click on image from admin site, I get 404 error `

Using the URLconf defined in chicyou.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    [name='index']

The current path, upload/shoe-1384193-1279x850.jpg, didn’t match any of these.
`

Comment: @Myk1709 can you show your MEDIA and MEDIA URL settings

Comment: `USERFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')`
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    USERFILES_DIRS,
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
`

Comment: @Myk1709 have you added this in project core URLs

**+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)**

Comment: @Myk1709 what does it prints **{{x.display_picture.url}}**

Comment: fount the answer here[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/) 
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
             path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` needed to be added with `urlpatterns` in project `urls.py`,
along with `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` defined in `settings.py` file

```
MEDIA_URL = '/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
```